# Insert Text with a shortcut key

Tags: c#, text, insert, onkeydown

I am inserting a text like 'xx--xx--xx\username' all the time. So I need something to insert a text after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>another key</kbd>.

After reading a bit about this problem I found some useful information:

[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key/1100374#1100374)

I have the problem to think how I can do this.
Any other person should define his own 'xx--xx--xx\username' like he need it. So saving this into a file is the next step.

Are there any threads on Stack Overflow about this problem? I couldn't find any results, maybe I was searching wrong.

Comment: What text do you want to insert and where in your textbox do you want to add it, at the front or back?

Comment: Hi Bernd, i want to insert a networkpath so i need here a string. I want to insert the text at the front. The text is getting saved after pressing the button in the folder so everytime i start the programm the saved text can be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the `KeyDown` event with which you detect if a user has pressed the keybord shortcut, handle the event `KeyDown` with this code (where `txtInput` is the `TextBox`)

```
this.txtInput.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.txtInput_KeyDown);
```

Now create that mentioned method (`txtInput_KeyDown`) and add the following code to handle specific shortcuts
(P.S. to handle the event and create the method in VisualStudio, just double click on the `KeyDown` even in the properties)

```
// Shortcut Alt+I
if (e.Alt && (e.KeyCode == Keys.I))
{
  txtInput.Text = @"somedomain\" + txtInput.Text; // Adds the text to the front of the current text
  txtInput.SelectionStart = txtInput.Text.Length; // Sets the cursor to the end of the text
}
// Shortcut Ctrl+K
else if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.K))
{
  txtInput.Text += @"networkpath\"; // Adds the text to the back of the current text
  txtInput.SelectionStart = txtInput.Text.Length; // Sets the cursor to the end of the text
}
```

As described in the comments in the code, this code will handle two different shortcut combinations differently, modify according to your needs.

Additional reading up can be done [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) regarding the KeyDown event.

The next step that you mentioned was to save the information and load it when the application starts up again, read the SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430008/save-user-settings-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396229/wpf-c-where-should-i-be-saving-user-preferences-files) regarding storing and retrieving user settings.

The MSDN entries regarding user settings:
[Using Application Settings and User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. Maybe i was not clear enough. Sry for this, but can i get the path into another window like the remoteconnection window. So my tool should work in the background and whenever i press the a defined key like alt + i it should insert it into the field where my mouse/front window is.

Comment: That will require Windows Messages to be passed between applications, I recommend researching this a bit and post a separate question when you are stuck